# Modify Docker Image

Tags: docker

So, let's say I have a set of containers that are based off of the image `some-image`.  `some-image` is based off of the `ubuntu` image.  Is it possible to update `some-image`, and have the aforementioned containers use the updated image?

Answer (score 2):

If your containers are built using Dockerfiles, and the Dockerfiles use `FROM some-image`, then you can update `some-image`, rebuild with the Dockerfiles, and the resulting images will be updated as well. (Which is why the Docker folks strongly encourage people to use Dockerfiles :-))

Comment: That's file, and I understood that bit, the only issue I have with that is that it requires rebuilding with Dockerfiles - I'd rather keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Rebuilding is the only method available now because the upper layers which depend on your base image may have to make their own installation decisions based on what is installed, what versions are there, etc. So changing the base layer without giving the upper layers a chance to adjust (during a rebuild) is asking for problems.